# $f:A\rightarrow B$ is left cancellable iff $f$ is injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a mapping. Then $f$ is injective if and only if the following condition is satisfied:

For any set $X$, two mappings $\phi:X\rightarrow A$ and $\psi:X\rightarrow A$ are equal if $f\circ \phi = f\circ \psi$.

Only-if part:

1. $f$ is injective
2. $\forall a \in A$ $(f(a_1) = f(a_2) \rightarrow \; a_1 = a_2)$
3. $f\circ \phi(x) = f\circ \psi(x) \; \forall x\in X$
4. $f(\phi(x)) = f(\psi(x)) \; \forall x\in X$
5. $\phi(x) = \psi(x) \; \forall x\in X$
6. $\phi = \psi$

if part:

1. Contrapositive: Suppose $f$ not injective, $\exists\;b_1,b_2\in B\;(b_1=b_2=f(a_1)=f(a_2)\rightarrow a_1\neq a_2)$ and $f\circ\phi = f\circ\psi$
2. $f(\phi(x)) = f(\psi(x)) \; \forall x\in X$
3. $\exists b_1,b_2\in B(b_1=b_2=f(\phi(x))=f(\psi(x))\rightarrow \phi(x)\neq\psi(x)$
4. $\phi\neq\psi$

Are the above correct?

Comment: In the only-if part step 2, you want $a_1 = a_2$ not $a_1 \neq a_2$

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I would edit it right away. Would be grateful if you could check whether the rest is right or not.

Comment: Your modified proof seems correct; but you do not need to use contraposition for if part: a direct proof follows from just taking $\phi$ and $\psi$ as constant functions.

Comment: $\phi(x)=a_1\forall x\in X$ and $\psi(x)=a_2\forall x\in X$ then by hypothesis $f(\phi(x))=f(\psi(x))\forall x\in X$ then $a_1=a_2\forall a_1,a_2\in A$ then by definition $f$ is injective. If this is the case, god u are so clever...i have never fathomed this